# Angular.js: How to store div HTML content in scope variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an editable `div` and I want to store the HTML content in `scope` variable `scope.myText`:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" ng-model="myText">
    <p>HTML Text</p>
</div>
```

How can I do that in Angular? Is there any directive to solve this problem? I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: What is the wysiwyg called? because there are angular plugins for tinymce https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce and ckeditor also but not sure how complete it is. Or even better if you just need a light text wysiwyg - http://textangular.com/

Comment: The html control you are seeing like text, input, etc. are actually all directives so that ng-model works. There is no directive for div.

Comment: Hi @Dylan, I'm using SnapEditor, I have made an implementation using ng-blur that works for me. Thanks for the suggestions I will take a look to textangular.

Comment: Have you considered this? http://textangular.com/

Comment: Yes, but I need one editor with floating toolbar, for that reason I'm using SnapEditor, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem using `ng-blur` directive:

Controller:

```
$scope.updateModel = function(){
    $scope.myText = angular.element(editor).html();
    //if you are using jquery use this line:
    //$scope.myText = $('#editor').html();
};
```

If you want to initialize the editor content use this:

```
angular.element(editor).html('<p>initial content</p>'); 
//thanks to @PatrickGrimard
```

or with jquery:

```
$('#editor').html('<p>initial content</p>');
```

View:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" data-ng-blur="updateModel()">
    <p>HTML Text</p>
</div>
{{myText}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a textarea inside your div instead, then you can just use ng-model on it.

Comment: No, I can't use a textarea, because the div is a WYSIWYG editor, and it doesn't use a textarea.

Comment: You could use angular.element() to get your div, then call .html() to get the contents and store it on the scope.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do that with angular.select? In the documentation angular.select refers to HTML component <select></select>.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to.  I'm making suggestions to a solution.